# stacked bar ggplot in log scale

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

I'm trying to do a stacked barplot with ggplot in R,using log_10 scale for the y-axis, but I'm getting the wrong plot.

This is my code:

```
library(reshape2)
library(ggplot2)

DF <- structure(list(Worker = 1:18, Seed = c(300, 40, 200, 0.1, 0.1, 
0.1, 1000, 0.1, 0.1, 30, 45, 0.1, 13, 0.1, 50, 0.1, 0.1, 30), 
Boosted = c(0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 
35, 0.1, 0.1, 13, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1), Online = c(0.1, 
0.1, 0.1, 15000, 60, 500, 0.1, 100, 450, 0.1, 200, 500, 0.1, 
5000, 0.1, 70, 1000, 500)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-18L))

DF1 <- melt(DF, id.var="Worker")

ggplot(DF1, aes(x = Worker, y = value, fill = variable)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  xlab("id") + 
  ylab("# of x") + 
  labs(fill = "") +
  scale_fill_manual(values = cols,
                    labels = c("Mobile", "Laptop","Online User")) + 
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18)) + 
  expand_limits(x = 1, y = 1) + 
  scale_y_log10(limits = c(1,1e5), 
                breaks = scales::trans_breaks("log10", function(x) 10^x),
                labels = scales::trans_format("log10", scales::math_format(10^.x)))
```

Below you see the image where the bars for some ids are wrong: see for instance ids 10 and 13.

What am I missing? I also tried just using `log(value)` in `ggplot(DF1, aes(x = Worker, y = log(value), fill = variable))`, but I'm getting the same.

[image]

Comment: A couple of lines of code seem to be missing from your example.

Comment: Yes, let me update it . Basically, have to reshape it

Comment: If I may editorialize, stacked bar charts are a confusing match for a log axis, as not only does the height not scale in proportion to the magnitude, but the ordering of the categories will change the interpretation of the same sized bar. For instance, does a bar from 10^0 to 10^1 represents 9 (10 - 1), or 10? Does a bar the same height from 10^1 to 10^2 represent 90?

Comment: log scales and bar charts are almost always a terrible combination (height does not map to quantity).  A stacked bar is even worse.  Best advice is to find a different way to present your data.